# Range Slider React hover, pressed and focus

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, babeljs

I have a range slider made with React(Babel) and CSS. I am trying to figure out how to add hover, active and focus effects(Changing the color of the thumb and left side of the slider). I have tried directly adding `:hover` to `input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb` but that doesn't work. I believe my main issue is stemming from the fact that the left part of the slider is styled with a `box-shadow` but I haven't found any other ways to handle this in documentation or Googling. Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 10px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -205px 0 0 200px red;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 0;
}

input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -1005px 0 0 1000px red;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript(Babel)

```
class VolumeSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 12.5
    };
  }

  onUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mb1">
        <input
          className="c-input--range"
          list="tickmarks"
          max={100}
          onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate(e)}
          step={0.1}
          type="range"
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <div>
           <label className="c-label">{this.state.value}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <VolumeSlider />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Code also provided in CodePen below. Thank you!

https://codepen.io/kcandle/pen/KKMrZKo

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign variables for the colors of the `box-shadow`

```
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      --slider-thumb-background-color: #000;
      background: var(--slider-thumb-background-color);
      border-radius: 50%;
      --box-shadow-color: orange;
      box-shadow: -205px 0 0 200px var(--box-shadow-color);
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      --border-color: orange;
      border: 3px solid var(--border-color);
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
      --slider-thumb-background-color: grey;
      --box-shadow-color: red;
      --border-color: red;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
      --slider-thumb-background-color: white;
      --box-shadow-color: blue;
      --border-color: blue;
    }
```